# Anything for C# Similar to Java JPA to build queries with Methods directly?

Tags: java, c#, hibernate, linq

got a quick question to see if there is anything for C# that is equivalent to the functionality that I use with Java's JPA an Hibernate for the findBy___ and findAllBy____ build queries / methods that you can do in Java - where you are able to create functions in Java to query the tables without having to write queries, you just need to write a method in your repository class with **findAllBy<*columnName*>EqualsAnd<*anotherColumnName*>Equals**?

Comment: such method is ultimately a query ...

Comment: Do you really need to though? C# has Linq, which does the query stuff, but doesn't produce those awful long method names.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I wouldn't necessarily need it, as linq has been a great tool, but would like to know if there is something equivalent for C# instead of using Linq to build a linq query.  I was just wanting to know if there was something that I could build methods like I can in Java to pass to the DB instead.